# Minimal home studio based on Focuserite Scarlett 6i6

Tags: audio-recording, audio-interfaces

I hope it is not too general question.

I am planning to have very minimal home studio with good quality sound recording into MacBookpro iOS 10.6.x. With friends we just need to connect a stage piano, 1 or 2 guitars and a phantom powered Mic. I would not need a MIDI atm but I feel like it is just a matter of time I will be using MIDI, either.

My favourite options is **Focuserite Scarlett 6i6** for £199.99. It seems to have what I'd need. It has 6 inputs, 2 phantom powered XLR mic inputs, 4 Line Inputs, MIDI In/Out, work with Apple comps, good sampling freq 96kHz and 24 bit audio resolution. It also has 2 monitor outputs, two headphone outputs but it needs external power. The latter would not be really an issue for me.

The only problem is that a guitar or two guitars and a mic would be a problem when there's only 2 mic inputs. What do you think? Can I plug an electric / acoustic guitar to line-in?

I am open to any suggestions :)

Cheers!

Comment: Good question, I just bought a Focusrite Scarlet 18i8 and am going to put it to the test today. I'll let you know how that goes. I've heard very good things about the Focusrite audio interfaces. However if the inputs are not enough then consider getting the 18i8, it's not too much more expensive. You should be able to hook up a mixer to add more mic inputs.

Comment: Yes you can plug your gtr into line-in but know that you set your input levels via software for all non-mic inputs on that interface.  I think the Scarlet 18i20 offers 8 combijacks if you are doubtful of the 6.  A Focusrite Octopre might be worth looking into.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for comments. I am looking forward to hearing from you MrTheBard :) The 18i8 is more expensive by £100 which is quite a bit. Perhaps it is worth. I'd like to make sure about one thing though. What does it exactly mean if there are 8 outputs. Does it mean I can connect this interface simultaneously to monitors, another mixer, and computer etc? Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a Look in digital mixing consoles ( behringer presonus). They combine mixing desks with interfaces so you can usb/firewire your mixing desc directly into your Mac! That would allow for multiple line/mics!

Good Day

Answer (score 1):

Check out the TASCAM US-1200, just released. Should meet your needs.

6 inputs, made up of 4 mic pres (with phantom) and 2 line inputs.
The line inputs can both be switched to Guitar Hi-Z.

No MIDI, but the price is great.
Does 96kHz.
Build in monitor mixer.
1 stereo output - line out + headphones, individual levels.

(I worked on the control panel software for this product).